# Rspec test cases not working

Tags: ruby, rspec

I probably have done some silly mistake but by running `rake` shows this

[image: rake]

Due to infinite loop it runs infinitely until i stopped it.

The folder structure follows :

[image: folder]

**calculator.rb**

```
class Calculator

    attr_accessor :result

    def initialize
        @result = 0.0
    end

    def add(param)
        @result += param
    end

    def subtract(param)
        @result -= param
    end

    def multiply(param)
        @result *= param
    end

    def divide(param)
        @result /= param
    end

    def cancel
        @result = 0.0
    end
end

class CommandProcessor
    attr_accessor :input
    attr_accessor :operation
    attr_accessor :calculator

    def parser
        calculator = Calculator.new
        while true
            input = gets.to_s.chomp
            operation = input.split(' ')[0]
            param = input.split(' ')[1]
            if operation.eql? 'exit'
                exit
            elsif operation.eql? 'add'
                calculator.add(param.to_f)
                puts calculator.result
            elsif operation.eql? 'subtract'
                calculator.subtract(param.to_f)
                puts calculator.result
            elsif operation.eql? 'multiply'
                calculator.multiply(param.to_f)
                puts calculator.result
            elsif operation.eql? 'divide'
                calculator.divide(param.to_f)
                puts calculator.result
            elsif operation.eql? 'cancel'
                calculator.cancel
                puts calculator.result
            else
                puts "invalid op"
            end
        end
    end
end

command = CommandProcessor.new
command.parser
```

**calculator_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require "calculator.rb"

describe "CommandProcessor" do
    it "will exit on input exit" do
        @cmd = CommandProcessor.new
        @cmd.stub!(:gets).and_return("add 3\n")
        @cmd.parser
        expect(@cmd.calculator.result).to eq 3
    end
end

describe "Calculator" do
    it "will add a number" do
        calculator = Calculator.new
        expect(calculator.add 2).to eq 2.0
        expect(calculator.add 2.0).to eq 4.0
    end

    it "will subtract a number" do
        calculator = Calculator.new
        expect(calculator.subtract 2).to eq -2.0
        expect(calculator.subtract 2.0).to eq -4.0
    end

    it "will multiply a number" do
        calculator = Calculator.new
        expect(calculator.multiply 2).to eq 0.0
        expect(calculator.multiply 2.0).to eq 0.0
    end

    it "will divide a number" do
        calculator = Calculator.new
        expect(calculator.divide 2).to eq 0.0
        expect(calculator.divide 2.0).to eq 0.0
    end

    it "will make result zero on cancel" do
        calculator = Calculator.new
        calculator.cancel
        expect(calculator.result).to eq 0.0
    end
end
```

Have i structured the code wrongly or my test are wrong? The code works fine but not the test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the prime culprit for the infinite loop, is the one you've introduced yourself, in `CommandProcessor#parser`.

I believe the problem is that you are stubbing `gets` on your object, but actually, it is defined on [`Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), so if you are going to stub it anywhere, that's where. This means that `gets` is probably returning some sort of nonsense that your parser does not understand, which leads to the infinite loop of `invalid op` that you see. It would probably be useful to print what the invalid op was in that case (i.e. change the `puts "invalid op"` to `puts "invalid op: #{operation}"`.)

It is worth noting that even if your stub had worked, and you kept getting `add 3` instead of garbage data, your programming would still loop forever, because the parser never receives an `exit`, which it needs to break from the loop.

In my opinion, this issue is indicative of another problem: You are trying to test two things in one go: The parser, and the IO. I would suggest altering your interface so that your `CommandProcessor.parse` took a string, parses it, and returns the result from the internal `Calculator` instance. Then it becomes almost trivial to test, which is what we want (nobody wants to think too hard).